# how does bluetooth device control volume button on iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Some Bluetooth devices can control the side button of iPhone without the help of any apps. Pushing the button on the Bluetooth device will have the same effect as pushing the volume button on your iPhone. How do those devices work? Does iOS define some special messages that when it received those messages from Bluetooth devices then it will press the corresponding button?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf This might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These devices are using classic Bluetooth profiles. These profiles are standard and they are supported inherently by iOS, you don't have to write any code for them. You can check out [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) link to see what profiles are implemented.

You can't control the volume with Bluetooth Low Energy without an app. With an application open it would be possible because the application could increase or decrease the volume.